# Подключение SVG спрайта

Tags: веб-программирование, svg, svg-спрайт

Здравствуйте. Хочу использовать на сайте картинки svg вместо png, скорее всего их спрайт. Интересует возможность масштабировать картинки (для разных устройств) и менять цвет (например при hover). Кроссбраузерность. Поддержка "старых" браузеров не принципиальна (будет поддерживать - хорошо, не будет - не страшно), анимация тоже не обязательна... Необходима обязательная поддержка IPAD, MAC OS, IPhone...

Как подключить svg спрайты написано много, есть споры, в основном статьи написанные несколько лет назад ... 
Подскажите, как это сделать по best practics в нынешних реалиях? (возможно личный опыт)
Использую SASS, возможно под него есть "заточенные" решения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поскольку Gulp является уже де-факто стандартом для сборки фронтенда, думаю, будет уместно сразу начать с предложения использовать для создания SVG-спрайта плагин [gulp-svg-sprites](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svg-sprites). Теперь что касается ваших вопросов:

- **возможность масштабировать** — поскольку это SVG, то проблем с масштабированием не будет даже исходя из аббревиатуры.
- **возможность менять цвет** — имеется, через CSS (в режиме `symbols`).
- **кроссбраузерность** — ИЕ9 и выше

Без дополнительных настроек результатом работы плагина gulp-svg-sprites будет SVG-файл со всеми вашими иконками в виде обычного спрайта, подобного PNG-спрайту, и CSS-файл со стилями вида `.%icon_name% {}`. При необходимости получить другие результаты на выходе, придется конфигурировать плагин. Плюс использования такого спрайта в том, что иконки можно использовать в псевдоэлементах. Минус — простыми способами перекрасить элемент спрайта нельзя (можно перекрасить через CSS-фильтры или заранее сгенерировать элемент во всех нужных цветах).

Также есть возможность сделать спрайт как набор элементов `symbol`, как группы, есть вариант с генерацией png-фоллбека. Если вы используете SASS в синтаксисе SCSS, то можно также получить сгенерированный SCSS-файл со стилями.

Comment: Насколько я понял, то при использовании данного плагина без настроек, изменить цвет картинки не получится, т.е. для  ховера нужно создавать отдельную картинку (делал картинку без fill, т.е. черную). масштабируется вроде нормально...

Comment: если прописать `fill` нужного цвета, то он применится, почему же нельзя

Comment: здесь https://fiddle.jshell.net/jzogL719/ я пробовал поменять цвет, не получается... svg и css сформировал плагин. Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: боюсь, при использовании в стандартном режиме менять цвет через цсс не получится, поскольку спрайт применяется как обычное фоновое изображение. могу вам посоветовать заранее создать файл с иконками в нужных цветах, с svg это достаточно просто. ну или если иконки у вас не черные, можно использовать фильтр `hue-rotate()`. вот есть статья с примерами https://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images

Comment: скажите ваше мнение о таком использовании http://glivera-team.github.io/svg/2016/06/13/svg-sprites-2.html

Comment: _"Gulp является уже де-факто стандартом для сборки фронтенда"_ - уже не факт. Там вебпак шевелится... и постепенно побеждает...

Comment: использование через `symbols`, по-моему, наиболее гибкий и мощный вариант, если не смущает лишняя разметка на странице.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну моё мнение таково — вебпак для большого и сложного JS, чтобы на модули нарезать, препроцессить, делать разные версии для разных браузеров, вот это вот всё.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется проще создать спрайт используя Symbol, в нем fill='inherit', и дальше уже манипулировать цветом svg.

```
<svg class="svg" style="fill:red">
    <use xlink:href="unit/img/sprite.svg#1"></use>
</svg>
```

соответсвенно и hover и т.п. описывать в class="svg".